# import React from "react"; resulting in Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and all the solutions I found for this problem used npm cli and suggested to use babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd. However I am using CDN and here is my code:-

1] Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="js/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/components/hello.jsx"></script>
</html>
```

where browser.min.js is actually babel
and the other two react files are of version 16.5.2


2] And hello.jsx:-

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This code throws an error at line 1 in hello.jsx saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation where they use a cdn? What exactly is browser.min.js? There has to be a compilation process regardless of when it happens because the browser can't understand jsx or es6 imports.

Comment: Here is the https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html documentation for using CDN. And the browser.min.js is actually babel that is used to compile jsx as they have done in their Hello World program https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html

Comment: @rv7 I am getting just the error Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier in the console for line 1 of  hello.jsx

Comment: @rv7 as I said that I am using their CDN not Node I get the error in the google chrome console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hello.jsx` is **JSX**. You need to indicate this to the browser by setting the script attribute.

This is done by setting the script **type** attribute to `text/babel` *e.g.*

```
<script type="text/babel" src="js/components/hello.jsx"></script>
```

The babel standalone script traverses the DOM for scripts with this attribute and replaces them with their transpiled equivalents.

**Edit**

A couple of changes to `hello.jsx`

- Remove the import statements

  `ReactDOM` and `React` are globals in the context of `window` object.
- Replace

  ```
  render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  ```

  with

  ```
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  ```

Comment: Now I am getting this error in the google chrome console:- Failed to load file:///Some/Location/hello.jsx:Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @ShashishekharHasabnis The .jsx file extension has become obsolete. Just use the normal .js file extension. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/87#issuecomment-234627904

Comment: @TomScholz tried to rename but no luck. Wait I shall post this as an another question.

Comment: The error in google chrome console about Cross origin request seems like you're serving the page on a different host and requesting `hello.jsx` from the filesystem. May I ask how exactly are you serving up `index.html`? If you doing so using your CDN. You want to serve `hello.jsx` also with your CDN and use request it in `index.html` using its absolute URL at the CDN and not a relative one.

Comment: OluwafemiSule, TomScholz Here is the posted question for the crossorigin problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795195/cannot-load-external-component-js-file